# HTML not passing parameter to java class

Tags: java, html, applet, parameter-passing

having a problem with a simple parameter passing from HTML-file to my java file.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<APPLET code="BPAppletRun" width="400" height="200">
<PARAM name="testing" value="It works." />
</APPLET>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my java class:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class BPAppletRun extends Applet {

    private static String bPUsers;

    public void init(){
        bPUsers = this.getParameter("testing");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics gr) {

        drawUsers(gr);

    }
    public static String getBPUsers(){
        return bPUsers;
    }
    public void drawUsers(Graphics gr){

        if(bPUsers!=null){
            gr.drawString(bPUsers, 30, 20);

        }
        else{
            gr.drawString("Not working.", 30, 20);
        }
    }


}
```

So it should print "It works.", but it just prints "Not Working.", when I run the html file.

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong?
Cheers.

Comment: FWIW, I've just tried your code here and the applet correctly displays *It works*.

Comment: what browser/system/java version do you use? I't works for me in chrome and firefox @ linux

Comment: Also Make sure that you .class file is the last version of your compiled Java file

Comment: Well, this is interesting, I'm using win7 64-bit and tried it out with chrome and inside eclipse.

Comment: Win 7 64 bit ff, chrome, ie.    It works.

Comment: Seems to be working now. I copied it out from my eclipse folders and ran it and it worked. Then I went and ran it from my eclipse folders and it worked there too. -_-

Thanks for the help, and sorry to bother with this nonsense. :)

Comment: no problem. delete the question if you can, so that it doesn't lie around unanswered forever :)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<PARAM name="testing" value="It works." />
```

To:

```
<PARAM name="testing" value="It works." >
```